# python regular expression. Extract text between patterns

Tags: python, regex

How to get all the values in between 'uniprotkb:' and '(gene name)' in the 'str' below:

```
str = 'uniprotkb:HIST1H3D(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3A(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3B(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3C(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3E(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3F(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3G(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3H(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3I(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3J(gene name)'
```

The result is:

```
HIST1H3D
HIST1H3A
HIST1H3B
HIST1H3C
HIST1H3E
HIST1H3F
HIST1H3G
HIST1H3H
HIST1H3I
HIST1H3J
```

Comment: Please don't name a variable 'str' -- you'll hide the built-in string class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using re.findall(), you can get all parts of a string that match a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> sstr = 'uniprotkb:HIST1H3D(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3A(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3B(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3C(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3E(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3F(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3G(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3H(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3I(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3J(gene name)' 
>>> re.findall(r'uniprotkb:([^(]*)\(gene name\)', sstr)

['HIST1H3D', 'HIST1H3A', 'HIST1H3B', 'HIST1H3C', 'HIST1H3E', 'HIST1H3F', 'HIST1H3G', 'HIST1H3H', 'HIST1H3I', 'HIST1H3J']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneliner:

```
astr = 'uniprotkb:HIST1H3D(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3A(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3B(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3C(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3E(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3F(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3G(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3H(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3I(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3J(gene name)'
[pt.split('(')[0] for pt in astr.strip().split('uniprotkb:')][1:]
```

Gives:

```
['HIST1H3D',
 'HIST1H3A',
 'HIST1H3B',
 'HIST1H3C',
 'HIST1H3E',
 'HIST1H3F',
 'HIST1H3G',
 'HIST1H3H',
 'HIST1H3I',
 'HIST1H3J']
```

I don't recommend regexp solutions, if runtime matters.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't bother with a regular expression:

```
s = 'uniprotkb:HIST1H3D(gene name)|uniprotkb:HIST1H3A(gene name)'  # etc

gene_names = []
for substring in s.split('|'):
    removed_first = substring.partition('uniprotkb:')[2]  # remove the first part of the substring
    removed_second = removed_first.partition('(gene name)')[0]  # remove the second part
    gene_names.append(removed_second)  # put it on the list
```

should do the trick. You could even one-liner it - the above is equivalent to:

```
gene_names = [substring.partition('uniprotkb:')[2].partition('(gene name)')[0] for substring in s.split('|')]
```