# Extract only the portion of a string between two regex patterns

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692667/python-regular-expression-extract-text-between-patterns) and although the answer solves the OP's problem it doesn't actually answer the question. How can I extract a section of a given string when only the pattern before and after the relevant section are known?

For example if I had a string like this:

`"Hi, this is a string where only values = { 000.10, 2.00, 5.0, 10.0 } are important`

And given this string I need to extract specifically `000.10, 2.00, 5.0, 10.0`. I don't know how many numbers there will be or their format, or even how many spaces there are in between them, but I know that `values = {` and `}` will be at the start and end.

Using a regular expression I can find `values = { 000.10, 2.00, 5.0, 10.0 }` by doing:

```
import re

string = "Hi, this is a string where only values = { 000.10, 2.00, 5.0, 10.0 } are important"

match = re.search(r'values\s=\s\{.+}\s', string)
if match:
    print match.group()
else:
    print "Could not find a match..."
```

Which outputs:

`values = { 000.10, 2.00, 5.0, 10.0 }`

So how can I get only the text between the patterns `r'values\s=\s\{` and `\}\s`?

I know that I could just replace the starting and end patterns with empty strings like this:

`match.group().replace('values = { ', '').replace(' } ', '')`

but is there a way to incorporate the fact that I only want the result between two patterns in the regular expression itself?

Hopefully this question makes sense. Any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to group the text you want, like this

```
re.search(r'values\s=\s{\s*(.+)\s*}\s', string)
```

Note the parens inside `{` and `}`. Here we use `\s*` to match 0 or more whitespace characters around the actual text which you want to match. Since the capturing group doesn't include the `\s*`, the whitespaces will not be matched. And then you will get the grouped value like this

```
print match.group(1)
```

When you do `match.group()`, or `match.group(0)` it will give the entire matched string. Since we want only the text matched by the group, we specify the number of the group. You can read more about it in the [`Match` object's `group`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) documentation.

Comment: According to OP's question, you need the capturing group between the curly braces =)

Comment: +1: Very simple explanation. To OP, the parens can also be position inside escaped brackets, ie. `\{`, similar to your original string to get *only* the numbers inside the brackets.

Comment: Ah, I see. That clarifies not only my question but the concept of groups in a match object. I guess there could potentially be multiple groups in the pattern marked by curly braces and could get any one of them via the group method. Nice!

Comment: You had better to allow for the empty string between the to regexps.  You have used `.+` and the two can be one after the other.  Just in case the empty string would be a valid result.

Comment: @LuisColorado You want me to change it to `.*`.

Comment: @thefourtheye, no, it was just to account for an empty pair of `{` and `}` with no data in between.  When I read the question I thought it was a general question about selecting the string in between two general regular strings.  Now, i see this is a very specific case... I think you had better to use `[^}]*` instead of `.+` to cope with the case `value = { a b c } d e }`  Don't know in that case what is the right response to the question.

Comment: @LuisColorado But `.+` is greedy. So, it would account for this case, right?

Comment: yeah, but not if what we want is the other.  Suppose you have `value = { a b c d e } .... some other stuff ... value = { f g h }`

Comment: @LuisColorado You are correct. But OP hasn't specified anything about it in the question. pbreach: What do you think about the case Luis brought up?

Comment: @thefourtheye I didn't see this until going back to the question for reference... but the comment brought up is a good point, however if I understood it correctly was not an issue for my purposes. I was just extracting / modifying values from specific arrays in a huge piece of java code where there was never empty space between the curly braces.